# Присвоение переменной на PHP

Tags: php

Есть конструкция, которая выводит результат 2 цифры:

```
 if (intval($z21a) > 0) { printf("%02d", intval($z21a)); } else { echo ''; }
```

Хочу сделать переменную $z21d равной этому коду:

```
 $z21d = if (intval($z21a) > 0) { printf("%02d", intval($z21a)); } else { echo ''; } ;
```

Происходит синтаксическая ошибка. Подскажите, что я не так сделал?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Синтаксическая конструкция if ничего не возвращает. Делайте присвоение из тела:

```
if (intval($z21a) > 0) { $z21d = sprintf("%02d", intval($z21a)); } else { $z21d = ''; }
```

Или используйте тернарный оператор:

```
$z21d = intval($z21a) > 0 ? sprintf("%02d", intval($z21a)) : '';
```

П.С.: Есть еще вариант работы с буфером, но это уже ближе к извращениям. =)